# Inline Javascript with Fat-Free Layouts

Tags: php, model-view-controller, fat-free-framework

I'm working with PHP Fat Free and I am attempting to create a layout/sublayout system which will eventually mimic MVC to some extent.  I have a main layout which has placeholders (essentially the backend sets different sublayout or partial file paths and then the view takes care of calling the rendering of that file name.  This all works great.

The issue I'm running into is when I need inline javascript in my sublayout to run after scripts in the main layout (after the jquery include line, for instance).  In a previous framework I was using, I was able to do us output buffering ob_start and ob_get_clean to grab the script in the sublayout and then pass that to the layout to display below the script line.  I hope that makes sense, but if not, here's the current code I'm working with in F3.

The route:

```
$f3->route('GET /test',
    function($f3) {
        // set the sublayout name
        $f3->set('sublayout', 'testpage.php');

        // render the whole shebang
        echo View::instance()->render('testlayout.php');
    }
);
```

The layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Layout</h1>
  <?php echo View::instance()->render($sublayout) ?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" />
  <!-- inline script should go here -->
</body>
</html>
```

The sublayout:

```
<h2>My Test Page</h2>
<div id='message'></div>

<script>
    // This code needs to be placed AFTER the jquery include in the main layout
    $(function(){
        $('#message').html('This is my message');
    });
</script>
```

I tried extending the view to include a "beginRegion" and endRegion function that basically handled the ob_start and ob_get_clean portion so that my inline script could be picked up, but once I'm in the sublayout I wasn't able to figure out how to pass that buffered code back to the layout so it could be echo'd after the jquery include.

Before you tell me that I should not be using inline script, I know this and most things I do are in external script files which I have a solution for including, but there are times when I need it inline and that's where I'm stuck.

Is there a way to handle what I'm trying to do with output buffering, or better yet is there a better way to solve this than the output buffering approach?

**Update:**
Best practices generally dictate that you should include the script at the bottom of the page right before the closing body tag. If I put the script above the sublayout, it breaks both our FE best practices and has the disadvantage of blocking the rest of the page while the script downloads.  That's why I'd like to keep it structured the way I have noted instead of placing the jquery include ABOVE the sublayout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what's the problem.
Your layout is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Layout</h1>
  <?php echo View::instance()->render($sublayout) ?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" />
  <!-- inline script should go here -->
</body>
</html>
```

You want to include sublayout after jquery usage. So why not to write it like this? :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Layout</h1>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" />
  <!-- inline script should go here -->
  <?php echo View::instance()->render($sublayout) ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also You can write custom function. Lets say You've folder with partials or something else more structured and want to use it:

```
$f3->set('partial',
    function($file) {
        $file .= (strpos($file, '.php')>0)? '' : '.php';
        if(!is_file($file)) return '';
        return View::instance()->render($file);
    }
);
```

and then use it like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Layout</h1>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" />
  <!-- inline script should go here -->
  {{ @partial('partials/testpage') }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I should clarify, and to answer your question about "So why not to write it like this?" Best practices generally dictate that you should include the script at the bottom of the page right before the closing body tag.  If I put the script above the sublayout, it breaks both our FE best practices and has the disadvantage of blocking the rest of the page while the script downloads.  I'll add this to the original post to clarify this point, and thx for the partial example.  I will use that in the future I'm sure.  Though, I'd have to adapt it as I'm not using F3 templating

Answer (score 0):

I knew why You want to do so. But what's the problem to decouple scripts in scripts.php file and HTML,php part to another file and render them as needed? (:

Comment: Yes, that is an option, and one I've contemplated before.  In the end, that might be the way to handle it, though I was trying to keep the inline code next to the relevant markup it was manipulating rather than having to jump to an external file to view it. Otherwise with the solution you're proposing I might as well just throw it in an external .js file and include it that way (as I mentioned I have a solution for pulling in js files, just not inline ones.)

Comment: Also I always keep in separate files layout code and js files, and at the end I minify all js part and include as one js file at the bottom.

Comment: Agreed, 99% of the time that's what I do as well.  Sometimes I include inline JS if I have to have the javascript be dynamic, as in passing a database ID from PHP to the script.

Answer (score 0):

From a google groups discussion I had, someone offered up a JS solution that might work:

inside your layout:

```
<head>
  <script>
  var callbacks=[];
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="...jquery.min.js"/>
  <script>
    $.each(callbacks,function(i,func){func.call(null,jQuery);}) //<< triggers all queued callbacks
  </script>
</body>
```

inside your sublayout:

```
<h2>My Test Page</h2>
<div id="message"></div>
<script>
  callbacks.push(function($){
    //do something with jQuery
  });
</script>
```

Here's the link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/iGcDuDueN8c

Comment: This gg discussion also offers a method using output buffering along with the javascript solution.  I'm going to mark this as the answer because it directly addresses all points of the the original issue with two viable solutions.  Thanks to @num8er as well for his help.